# Display sum of mutlple rows value in single column between date range using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I  have following sql query.

```
SELECT E.EMPID, TM.LOGIN, TM.LOGOUT, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)/60)+':'+
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)%60) AS WORKEDHOURS   
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS E  
LEFT JOIN TIMING_DETAILS TM  
    ON(E.EMPID=TM.EMPID)  
WHERE TM.LOGIN BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-03')  
GROUP BY E.EMPID,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT  
ORDER BY E.EMPID
```

After running above query, I get following output :

```
EMPID   LOGIN               LOGOUT          WORKEDHOURS  
1     2-9-2013 9:30      2-9-2013 1:00          3:30
1     2-9-2013 2:00      2-9-2013 6:00          4:00

2     2-9-2013 9:30      2-9-2013 2:00          4:30
2     2-9-2013 3:00      2-9-2013 6:00          3:00

1     3-9-2013 9:30      3-9-2013 6:00          8:30
```

But, I want to display result as follows, Anybody please help here, thanks

```
EMPID   LOGIN               LOGOUT          WORKEDHOURS
1     2-9-2013 9:30      2-9-2013 1:00          7:30
1     2-9-2013 2:00      2-9-2013 6:00          

2     2-9-2013 9:30      2-9-2013 2:00          7:30
2     2-9-2013 3:00      2-9-2013 6:00          

1     3-9-2013 9:30      3-9-2013 6:00          8:30
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` clause includes `TM.LOGIN` and `TM.LOGOUT`, which prevents the sum from covering multiple rows.  That's why you'are getting a result per row, rather than per `E.EMPID`.

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé : When i remove `TM.LOGIN` and `TM.LOGOUT`, from `GROUP BY`, it gives error `Column 'TIMING_DETAILS.LOGIN' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: That message is correct.  Aggregate data and non-aggregate data don't belong together.  For one thing it breaks the semantics of the data.  You should consider either a) splitting this out into separate queries (one to aggregate time, and another to list specific time periods), or b) use the query you have, and sum the hours in code.  You might be able to mangle a query to give the output presented, but this intentionally breaks the semantics of the table result.

Comment: Based on your dialogue with Szymon, it seems you only need the data in the first row for each `EMPID`. (Presumably, you then don't actually need the different values of `LOGIN` and `LOGOUT`.) If so drop remove `TM.LOGIN` and `TM.LOGOUT` from both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ kevin: yes i need date in first row for each `EMPID` but i also need  `M.LOGIN` and `TM.LOGOUT`

Comment: Oh, that makes this problem quite manageable.  I'll post a solutions.

Comment: In the solution I posted, I offer two approaches, but I think the last one is actually what you want.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, found a simpler solution:

```
    SELECT T.EMPID, T.LOGIN, T.LOGOUT, X.WORKEDHOURS
FROM TIMING_DETAILS T
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT EMPID, DATEPART(YEAR, TM.LOGIN) YEAR, DATEPART(MONTH, TM.LOGIN) MONTH, DATEPART(DAY, TM.LOGIN) DAY,
        CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT))/60 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
        + ':' 
        + CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT))%60 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS WORKEDHOURS
    FROM TIMING_DETAILS TM
    WHERE TM.LOGIN BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-03') 
    GROUP BY EMPID, DATEPART(YEAR, TM.LOGIN), DATEPART(MONTH, TM.LOGIN), DATEPART(DAY, TM.LOGIN)) X
ON X.EMPID = T.EMPID 
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, T.LOGIN) = X.YEAR
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, T.LOGIN) = X.MONTH
    AND DATEPART(DAY, T.LOGIN) = X.DAY
ORDER BY X.EMPID, X.YEAR DESC, X.MONTH DESC, X.DAY DESC
```

Comment: Found a simpler solution

Comment: in above query date range condition part is missing as per my query, but i added and executed but same output is coming as after running my above query

Comment: Sorry, removed the condition when testing it.
Do you mean it's not giving you the total time against each row?

Comment: Also, I had to add grouping on date to separate times for each date

Comment: its k,total time is coming against each row, but i want to display total time only in one column as per each employee regardless of how many row has entered, please see my desired output, and i will try your edited query

Comment: You normally don't do this kind of things in a sql query. Where are you using the results? It may be easier to display only in the first row in the client.

Comment: exactly you are write, i am displaying only first row to client, so(i take first output from my question for `empid =1`, it displays `worked hours =3:30` rather than `7:30`

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Don't my query display 7:30 twice?

Comment: Sorry, now output is coming correctly, but in above query date range condition is missing, when i put date range before `GROUP BY` like `WHERE TM.In_LOGIN BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-06')` clause then for some employee `workedhours` is coming in ascending order(2sep-6sep) but for some is descending order(6sep-2sep)

Comment: See my edit. I put back the `WHERE` clause and added ordering. I'm not sure if you want ascending or descending, you can change that yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot... i got the desired output, but you have written query using  only one table, if possible could you please edit the query using both tables

Comment: I used only one table as the columns in select clause don't require the other table. Do you need to return more columns?

Comment: yes, i need to return more column from first table i.e. `EMPLOYEE_DETAILS`

Comment: You can just make another join on T.EMPID to the second table. Do you want to give it a go?

Comment: please write, i was trying but didn't get yet :(

Comment: Great, I'm happy you found the solution.

Comment: thanks, but now i was trying to print worked hours only to the the first row for each `EMPID`, but yet didn't get succeed, do you have any idea on that

Comment: You could use `RANK` (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) but that's getting much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.EMPID, TM.LOGIN, TM.LOGOUT,WORKHOURS_TABLE.WORKEDHOURS

FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS E, TIMING_DETAILS TM ,

(SELECT EMPID,
concat(
sum(hour(timeDIFF(TM.LOGOUT, TM.LOGIN )))
+ 
sum(minute(timeDIFF(TM.LOGOUT, TM.LOGIN ))) div 60 ,
":" , 
sum(minute(timeDIFF(TM.LOGOUT, TM.LOGIN ))) % 60
)

AS WORKEDHOURS 
FROM TIMING_DETAILS TM
GROUP BY EMPID) AS WORKHOURS_TABLE

WHERE E.EMPID =  WORKHOURS_TABLE.EMPID AND E.EMPID=TM.EMPID  
ORDER BY E.EMPID
```

The output might be :

```
EMPID   LOGIN               LOGOUT          WORKEDHOURS
1     2-9-2013 9:30      2-9-2013 1:00          7:30
1     2-9-2013 2:00      2-9-2013 6:00          7:30

2     2-9-2013 9:30      2-9-2013 2:00          7:30
2     2-9-2013 3:00      2-9-2013 6:00          7:30
```

If you want to group by date then you have to keep a separate column for `date` and `time`, and then you can group by date.

I have tried the query in  my MySQL database and it works fine. You try it out.

Comment: Sory, this error is coming :`Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "TM.LOGIN" could not be bound.`

Comment: can you send `create table` statements for those tables.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS    
(    
 EMPID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    
 NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL    
)    

CREATE TABLE TIMING_DETAILS    
(    
EMPID int NOT NULL,    
LOGIN datetime NULL,    
LOGOUT datetime NULL,    
FOREIGN KEY (EMPID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_DETAILS(EMPID)    
)`

Comment: sorry i am using sql server, above query doesn't have date range as per my question but i tried without that, total hours is coming wrong(e.g. emp1 date from 2sep-3sep workedhours:517:49 for all dates rather than different on each date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  
      t.EMPID
    , t.LOGIN
    , t.LOGOUT
    , WORKEDHOURS = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t.WORKEDHOURS END
FROM (
    SELECT 
          TM2.EMPID
        , TM2.LOGIN
        , TM2.LOGOUT
        , TM.WORKEDHOURS
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TM2.EMPID ORDER BY TM2.EMPID) 
    FROM dbo.TIMING_DETAILS TM2
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
              EMPID
            , WORKEDHOURS = CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [login], LOGOUT)) / 60 AS VARCHAR(100)) + ':' + CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [login], LOGOUT)) % 60 AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        FROM dbo.TIMING_DETAILS
        WHERE [login] BETWEEN '20130902' AND '20130904'
        GROUP BY EMPID
    ) TM ON TM2.EMPID = TM.EMPID
    WHERE EXISTS( -- maybe this is unnecessary
         SELECT 1
         FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE_DETAILS E
         WHERE E.EMPID = TM2.EMPID 
    )
) t
```

Comment: Sorry, error is coming , `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "TM2.LOGIN" could not be bound`

Answer (score 0):

After our dialogue, and also reviewing your dialogue with other participants, I see that your problem is slightly more constrained.  The output you actually want is something like this:

```
EMPID   DAY          WORKEDHOURS
    1   2-9-2013     7:30
    1   3-9-2013     8:30
    2   2-9-2013     7:30
```

**CASE 1: single day in range**

If you are only interested in a single day, then you can just insert the date into the result.  Please try the following:

```
SELECT E.EMPID,
       '2013-09-02' AS DAY,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)/60)+':'+
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)%60) AS WORKEDHOURS   
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS E  
     LEFT JOIN TIMING_DETAILS TM  
     ON (E.EMPID=TM.EMPID)  
WHERE TM.LOGIN BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-03')
GROUP BY E.EMPID
ORDER BY E.EMPID
```

You can also rewrite your query to use a named parameter for the date in question.  Here is an example, but to use it you will have to bind a value to the parameter `TheDay`:

```
SELECT E.EMPID,
       @TheDay AS DAY,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)/60)+':'+
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)%60) AS WORKEDHOURS   
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS E  
     LEFT JOIN TIMING_DETAILS TM  
     ON (E.EMPID=TM.EMPID)  
WHERE TM.LOGIN BETWEEN @TheDay AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @TheDay)
GROUP BY E.EMPID
ORDER BY E.EMPID
```

**CASE 2: multiple days in range**

If you need multiple rows per EMPID, but only one such row per day, then things are more complicated.  I think it is possible in several (perhaps all) DBMSs, but might require using non-portable features.  What we need to do is `GROUP BY` the day part of the `LOGIN` date-time value.

If you are using SQL Server 2008 (or newer), then you can try the following:

```
SELECT E.EMPID,
       CAST(TM.LOGIN AS DATE) AS DAY,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)/60)+':'+
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)%60) AS WORKEDHOURS   
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS E  
     LEFT JOIN TIMING_DETAILS TM  
     ON (E.EMPID=TM.EMPID)  
WHERE TM.LOGIN BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-03')
GROUP BY E.EMPID, CAST(TM.LOGIN AS DATE)
ORDER BY E.EMPID
```

Note that I have not been in a position to test this query.  You may, for example, have to `GROUP BY DAY` instead of repeating the expression.

**CASE 2B: multiple days in range, with first and last login**

Do you want one row per day per EMPID, but the first login time, and the last logout time?  You could try the following:

```
SELECT E.EMPID,
       MIN(TM.LOGIN) AS FIRSTLOGIN,
       MAX(TM.LOGOUT) AS LASTLOGOUT,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)/60)+':'+
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TM.LOGIN,TM.LOGOUT)%60) AS WORKEDHOURS   
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS E  
     LEFT JOIN TIMING_DETAILS TM  
     ON (E.EMPID=TM.EMPID)  
WHERE TM.LOGIN BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-03')
GROUP BY E.EMPID, CAST(TM.LOGIN AS DATE)
ORDER BY E.EMPID
```

Again, I have not been in a position to test this query.

**TESTED CASE: A query on a local SQL Server Express database within Visual Studio 2010**

I am not able to test on Sql Server today, but here is a version of the query that I have tested under Visual Studio 2010 on a local Sql Server Express database.

```
SELECT
    E.EMPID, E.NAME,
    MIN(TM.LOGIN) AS FirstLogIn,
    MAX(TM.LOGOUT) AS LastLogOut,
    CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TM.LOGIN, TM.LOGOUT) / 60) AS NVARCHAR)+':'+CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TM.LOGIN, TM.LOGOUT) % 60) AS NVARCHAR) AS WorkedHours
FROM
    EMPLOYEE_DETAILS AS E LEFT OUTER JOIN TIMING_DETAILS AS TM ON E.EMPID = TM.EMPID
WHERE
    TM.LOGIN BETWEEN '2013-09-21' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-22')
GROUP BY
    E.EMPID, E.NAME,
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, TM.LOGIN), 0)
ORDER BY
    E.EMPID, FirstLogin
```

Test data EMPLOYEE_DETAILS:

```
EMPID    NAME
1        Joe
2        Jane
3        Martha
```

Test data TIMING_DETAILS:

```
EMPID    LOGIN                    LOGOUT
1        '2013-09-21 09:00:00'    '2013-09-21 10:30:00'
1        '2013-09-21 14:00:00'    '2013-09-21 16:00:00'
1        '2013-09-22 08:30:00'    '2013-09-22 11:00:00'
2        '2013-09-21 10:45:00'    '2013-09-21 13:30:00'
```

Results:

```
EMPID    NAME   FirstLogIn               LastLogOut               WorkedHours
1        Joe    '2013-09-21 09:00:00'    '2013-09-21 16:00:00'    3:30
1        Joe    '2013-09-22 08:30:00'    '2013-09-22 11:00:00'    2:30
2        Jane   '2013-09-21 10:45:00'    '2013-09-21 13:30:00'    2:45
```

That seems correct to me.  The only differences in my SQL Server Express query is that it does not provide the DATE type, so I had to modify the CAST.  Oh, and I had to explicitly cast to NVARCHAR for WorkedHours as well.

Please adapt accordingly for your environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your last query is same as i mentioned query in my above question, so i am getting same out rather than desired output mentioned in my question

Comment: @User12345 What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: @User12345 Alright. I have posted a query that I think will work for you. It works under SQL Server Express. Please adapt accordingly.